# ArgumentException 'child' is not a child control of this parent

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a Windows Form with a [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx). In this [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) are other Panels.

[Panel1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel1.aspx) contains a custom control called `InputControl` and a [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) called `Display`.

To find out which item is currently displayed, I turned to the [GetChildIndex Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fz293fh.aspx) and used the Windows Form as the parent:

```
int inputIndex = parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(InputControl);
int displayIndex = parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(Display);
```

When I was coding this, I was not sure if I could pass the Windows Form in as the parent, so I put a breakpoint afterwards to check that the two indexes were greater than -1:

```
      if ((-1 < inputIndex) && (-1 < displayIndex)) {
```

However, before the first integer `inputIndex` was assigned a value, I was awarded the [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) with this message for my efforts:

> 'child' is not a child control of this parent.

OK, I suppose these are not direct child controls of this parent.

The [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx), on the other hand, certainly is a direct child control. So, should I search the [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx) control?

Technically, the controls I want the z-index of are in the [Panel1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.panel1.aspx) control, though. Does that mean my code has to look this ugly?

```
int inputIndex = splitControl1.Panel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(InputControl);
int displayIndex = splitControl1.Panel1.Controls.GetChildIndex(Display);
```

This seem like a very unhelpful way of getting the z-indexes for my two (2) controls.

Is there a simpler way to go about this other than writing my own code to keep track of which control is on top?

I'd like some Microsoft method that returns the z-index of any control, whether that control be a direct child control or some sort of other descendant of the parent. The answer is awarded, first, to the person who knows this.

If that doesn't exist, how would I write one without having to create recursive loops? In the absence of an existing Microsoft method, this would serve as awarded answer.

If a recursive loop is necessary, points (and possibly answer) to best recursive loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
var inputIndex = InputControl.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(InputControl);
var displayIndex = Display.Parent.Controls.GetChildIndex(Display);
```

Comment: This could also be added as an extension method of `Control` if you really want it short.

Comment: Damn Michael. You made it look so easy. I spent a while working on this, too.

Answer (score 1):

When you have splitcontainer or other containers they recieve an tabindex
based on the controls in the parent control(ex: Form1)
ex: Form1 with 2 buttons,1 textbox and splitcontainer
-depending on the order you placed them or if you edited their order...
button1 tabindex would be 0,button2 1,textbox 2,splitcontainer 3

Now,inside splitcontainer you have 2 panels(1 and 2)which recieve their
proper index....splitcontainer.panel1 will recieve tabindex of 3,0
and splitcontainer.panel2 will be 3,1......now inside each you put controls,
so their tabindex would be 3,0,0 or 3,0,1 depending on how many controls you have inside
but i think you get the picture
think of those containers like "Form" with their own index.

ex: int y = this.Controls.Find("Display", true).Single(x => x.Name == "Display").TabIndex;

this will get the index inside the panel of the splitcontainer that the control
is on.

Michael Gunter answer is the correct one
Hope this will help a bit

Comment: Hi Terry and welcome to StackOverflow! Let me give you your first +1; however, **TabIndex** is not what I needed. I needed something called the **z-index**.